# How to create dynamic table layout of JSON data with sorting android?

Tags: android, tabular

I have an application in which I have a requirement to display dynamic content from JSON data in the tabular format with borders. I tried creating it with the static data but I also need sorting in this functionality. There is 1 library which I have referred:

https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView

In this open source library they provide sorting but width of table is fixed. I need varible height and width for this component.

Does anyone knows how to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have u tried using TableLayout

Comment: exaple also available with it.https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/de/codecrafters/tableviewexample ,please gothrout it.

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani: I have tried its example, the problem with the example is that they are allowing setting width but horizontal scroll is not available. Whenever I try to set Horizontal scrollview to the component, the view disappears.

Comment: @Nainal: I tried using Tablelayout but setting the header with sorting makes things complex. Do you have any examples on Tablelayout with sorting and header improvements?

Comment: Sorry! but I don't have sample code right now. you can refer the link http://www.prandroid.com/2014/05/creating-table-layout-dynamically-in.html